# how to extract points attribute in st_geometry object in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, blob, esri

I would like to extract shape data from a table. I can get entity,numpts,minx,miny all the attributes except POINTS which is is BLOB. I would like to get the data as varchar.  How can I extract points attrribute's value in sd.st_geometry column  ?

**SOLUTION:I did extract POINTS attribute as treat(shape as sde.st_geometry).points as points. Thanks.**

This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE X
(
  OBJECTID      INTEGER                         NOT NULL,
  GRID_ID       VARCHAR2(17 BYTE),
  H3_10_INT_ID  VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
  CITY_NAME        VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  DISTRICT_NAME      VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  NEIGHBOURHOOD_NAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  SHAPE         SDE.ST_GEOMETRY
)
LOB ("SHAPE"."POINTS") STORE AS SECUREFILE (
  TABLESPACE  TBS_X
  ENABLE      STORAGE IN ROW
  CHUNK       8192
  CACHE
  LOGGING
      STORAGE    (
                  INITIAL          104K
                  NEXT             1M
                  MINEXTENTS       1
                  MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                  PCTINCREASE      0
                  BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
                 ))
TABLESPACE TBS_X
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    0
INITRANS   4
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          400K
            NEXT             1M
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
MONITORING;
```

This is one sample of the table.

Insert into X
(OBJECTID, GRID_ID, H3_10_INT_ID, CITY_NAME,
DISTRICT_NAME, NEIGHBOURHOOD_NAME)
Values
(133, '8a1ec8000537fff', '622038258059280383', 55498, 'Tekirdag',
'Suleymanpasa', 'Osmanli');
COMMIT;

You can see the sample shape object when I double click

[image]

```
SELECT objectid,sde.st_entity(SHAPE),sde.st_numpoints(SHAPE),
sde.st_minx(SHAPE),sde.st_miny(SHAPE),sde.st_maxx(SHAPE),sde.st_maxy(SHAPE),sde.st_minz(SHAPE),sde.st_maxz(SHAPE),sde.st_maxm(SHAPE),sde.st_area(SHAPE),
sde.st_length(SHAPE),
sde.st_srid(SHAPE)
FROM X
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; an explanation of the logic that you want to implement (i.e. what format, etc. do you want to get the points as); and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: I edited the question with create and insert statements thanks

Comment: Your `INSERT` does not provide a [MRE] as you never insert anything into the `shape` column so it will be `NULL`. Please provide a way to replicate the problem and also explain what format you want the output as.

Comment: I have selected the output of select *from x where objectid=1 then I clicked the export dataset and  chosen export dataset as insert statements and then got this result. I dont know why the exported insert statement as like this. You may try also according to the image I have inserted above and try it you will see what I mean. Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE X
(
  OBJECTID           INTEGER           NOT NULL,
  SHAPE              ST_GEOMETRY
);

INSERT INTO x (objectid, shape)
VALUES (
  1,
  ST_LINESTRING(
    ST_POINT_ARRAY(
      ST_POINT(1, 2, 4326),
      ST_POINT(3, 4, 4326),
      ST_POINT(5, 6, 4326)
    )
  )
);
```

Then you can use:

```sql
SELECT objectid,
       TREAT(x.shape AS ST_LINESTRING).ST_NUMPOINTS() AS numpoints,
       p.*
FROM   x
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT p.st_x() AS x,
                p.st_y() AS y
         FROM   TABLE(TREAT(x.shape AS ST_LINESTRING).ST_POINTS()) p
       ) p
```

Which outputs:

| OBJECTID | NUMPOINTS | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NgRvYyRW)

Comment: I am getting error -> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected SDE.ST_GEOMETRY got MDSYS.ST_LINESTRING

Comment: When I double click "Points"  (hugeblob) I get only dot (.)

Comment: I did extract POINTS attribute as  treat(shape as sde.st_geometry).points as points. Thanks.